# Create Custom Checkbox tree view component Angular

Tags: angular, components, directive, custom-component

I want to create Tree View component in Angular with checkbox.
Please find my code at -

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvzr8c

Here I am able to render tree View on UI. But want to implement functionality  -

1. When Parent checkbox is checked then all its child check box should be checked automatically.
2. When all child checkboxes checked  then parent node chekbox should automatically selected.
3. At the end want list of all selected checkboxes.

Here how can I set model to checkboxes and achieve above functionality.​

Answer (score 4):

the first you need is add a new optional property to your TreeNode

```
interface TreeNode {
    label: string;
    check?:boolean; //<--this one
    children: TreeNode[];
  }
```

After you can use [ngModel] in the input, and (ngModelChange) to call a function "selectNode"

```
 <label class="node__label">
        <input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="node.check" 
          (ngModelChange)="selectNode(node,$event)"/>
    {{ node.label }}
</label>
```

the seletNode is a function that call a recursive function:

```
  public selectNode( node: TreeNode,value:boolean ) : void {
        this.check(node,value)
  }

  check(node:any,value:boolean)
  {
    node.check=value;
    node.children.forEach(x=>
    {
      this.check(x,value)
    })
  }
```

You can see in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7r4t9p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

But you can take account the suggest of @Dseroski and not re-invent the wheel :)

Comment: Thank you Eliseo. Actually here we want to create completely custom tree view no other plugin we can 
 use. Here one more question I have please suggest - When child is unchecked then all its parents become uncheck. How can I proceed in that? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Angular Material has a pretty good Tree module. This example is explicitly similar to what you need, aside from a few logic changes on checking a box.

https://stackblitz.com/angular/baxxqmgxmgq?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-checklist-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

Please try with [this](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/treeview/check-box/) plugin. It will works for you.